# PHP Mysqli error: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Tags: php, mysqli

this is not a question, I need your help. I read similar threads but   I couldn't debug the problem in my code. Could you plz give the correct solution?

```
<?php
/*variable declaration*/
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dbname='mydatabase';

/*connection to mysql server*/
$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);

/*selecting database*/
$selectdb=mysqli_select_db($connect,$dbname);

if(!$selectdb){
    echo 'Failed to connect. Wrong username or database.';
}else{
    echo 'Connection successful.';
}

/*creating task*/
$query = "SELECT 'Name', 'Password' FROM 'db' ORDER BY 'id'";

if(mysqli_query($selectdb,$query)){
echo 'Success';
}else{
echo '<br>Failed';
}
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ABe.png)

Comment: `$connect ` need to provide instead of `$selectdb` in  `mysqli_query($selectdb,$query)`

Comment: Pass only one parameter  mysqli_query($selectdb); instead of mysqli_query($selectdb,$query);

Comment: @ManishaChaudhary  mysqli_query(...) allway expects 2 parameters. But he needs to use the right ones.

Comment: you should write like this mysqli_query($query); actually, i wrote wrong in previous post. sorry for that

Comment: no need to write mysqli_query($selectdb, $query); because you have connected your database at middle top that line is $selectdb=mysqli_select_db($connect,$dbname); then why are you passing $selectdb in mysqli_query($selectdb, $query);

Comment: @ManishaChaudhary mysqli_query requires exactly 2 parameters & even if a connection has been made before making the query, correct parameters have to be used in mysqli_query('','',); plz check here [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify

```
$query = "SELECT 'Name', 'Password' FROM 'db' ORDER BY 'id'";
```

To

```
$query = "SELECT `Name`, `Password` FROM db ORDER BY 'id'";
```

You just cannot use the quotes on column name on the query, either use backticks or nothing at all.

Comment: This is true and a syntax-misstake, but not the cause auf the error he has.

Comment: @William Madede The problem was resolved by using back-ticks instead of quotes. BTW you missed back-ticks on [db].

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysqli_query($connect,$query)){...
```

In this you need to use the `$connect` and not the `$selectdb`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*variable declaration*/
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dbname='mydatabase';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);

/*I avoided this line & used $connect inside if() statement which worked    perfectly*/
//$selectdb = mysqli_select_db($connect,$dbname);

if(!$connect){
    echo 'Failed to connect. Wrong username or database.';
}else{
    echo 'Connection successful.';
}

/*creating task*/
$query = "SELECT `Name`, `Password` FROM `db` ORDER BY `id`";

if($query_run = mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
echo 'Success';
}else{
echo '<br> Failed';
}
```